# scriptdir=`dirname $0` not working

Tags: unix, shell-script

I am trying to get the directory where my script is in by using:

```
scriptdir=`dirname $0`
```

but this gives me the following error:

```
dirname: invalid option -- 'b'
Try `dirname --help' for more information.
```

and I tried what they recommended (i.e `dirname --help`) and it said command not found. How can I fix this problem?

I am trying to use the  scriptdir variable so I can compile the following java program:

```
java -mx800m -cp "$scriptdir/*" edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser -retainTmpSubcategories -outputFormat "typedDependencies"  -outputFormatOptions "basicDependecies" edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz ./sentences/100000.txt > ./parsedsentences/100000.txt
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`dirname -- "$0"`

The **--** (dash dash) stops `dirname` from processing any options in the argument. Always quote `$0` in case there are spaces in the name.

Answer (score 3):

use quotes. It may fix your issue.

```
scriptdir=`dirname -- "$0"`
```

I personnaly prefer this notation in bash scripts, but it is not mandatory:

```
scriptdir="$(command dirname -- "${0}")"
```

**EDIT:**

You may find the answer in the replies to [script full name and path $0 not visible when called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708339/script-full-name-and-path-0-not-visible-when-called).

**EDIT 2:**

Integraded the right answer.

Comment: I added another option to my answer.

Comment: $0 is '-bash' (ie. a login shell)

Comment: `bash ~ $scriptdir="$(command dirname "${0}")"
dirname: opción inválida -- 'b'
Try 'dirname --help' for more information.
bash ~ $
`